# Wrapper library for avrdude

Tags: android, arduino, ftdi, avrdude

The problem:
Through an Android app, be able to programmatically verify arduino flash contents to ensure it has not been changed (maliciously)

I am able to do that with avrdude using the command as below in the android adb shell

```
avrdude -C/data/data/com.myapp.avrdude/local/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v2 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:v:firmware.hex:i
```

This works well with arduino, but the problem comes in when I want to do the same with a board that uses an FTDI chip. When it's connected to the android device it does not show up in /dev/ location.

On a linux machine the arduino device appears as /dev/ttyACM0, and the FTDI device is /dev/ttyUSB0. The problem is the FTDI device does not appear on android therefore the avrdude command above becomes useless.

I do not want to build the kernel driver for FTDI as specified [here](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=285)

The approach I want to go with which I think is most viable is to find/build a simple java wrapper for avrdude that interacts with the usb device at a higher level, this way I can make use of the [FTDI java library](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) to execute a command to verify flash.

Is this approach viable? If not, what is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the FTDI site, it looks as though there may be a driver for some FTDI ICs: [FTDI Android Driver](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_147_Java_D2xx_for_Android.pdf)
You may then well be building avrdude again in java ha.

I have used avrdude often when using arduino...mainly to remote re-format/upgrade firmware on a 3D printer from a raspberrypi...

I'd go

1) Look into the Arduino Driver...

2) if fail...Maybe try down the avenue of running C programs in java? So you can package avrdude with your app?

3) XY Problem -> Why not look at other avenues...The only way to really pop malicious firmware on is with physical access to the device and with a user that has the prior source code (you can set lock bits to prevent reading EEPROM). Even a timestamped and UUID 1024bit AES token/JWT like thing could be used on startup to verify the build?

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface
```

Answer (score 1):

building for `JNI` won't help while `avrdude` wasn't built with `FTDI` support.

I've downloaded [avrdude-6.3.tar.gz](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/avrdude-6.3.tar.gz) and ran `./configure --enable-linuxgpio`:

```
Configuration summary:
----------------------
...
DON'T HAVE libftdi1
DON'T HAVE libftdi
...
```

when looking for it:

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides */libftdi1
```

it gives me:

```
libftdi-devel-1.1-4.el7.x86_64 : Header files and static libraries for libftdi
Filename : /usr/include/libftdi1
```

`sudo yum install libftdi-devel` also installs `libconfuse`. it also needs `flex` and `bison`.

there are even drivers for [D2XX](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) and [FT4222H](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT4222H.html).

see [AN_357 Android D2XX Demo Application for FT4222H](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_357%20Android%20Java%20D2xx%20Demo%20Application%20for%20FT4222.pdf).

and there are builds for ARM [libft4222-linux-1.4.1.231.tgz](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/libft4222-linux-1.4.1.231.tgz)

... which would go into the `jniLibs/armeabi` directory.

it depends which chipset it is, but the [TN 134 FTDI Android D2XX Driver](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_134_FTDI_Android_D2XX_Driver.pdf) states:

> To accompany the native D2XX library, **FTDI have provided a Java class and a JNI wrapper** which can be
>   easily included in an application. The class provides access to all of the classic D2XX functions including
>   EEPROM functions.

it even comes with a [video install guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jynlynjOOek).

also found the Arduino [build-script](https://github.com/arduino/avrdude-build-script/blob/master/avrdude-6.3.build.bash) for `avrdude`.

Comment: https://github.com/syslogic/avrdude-jni/blob/master/avrdude/src/main/cpp/Android.mk builds `avrdude` with `NDK`. `avrdude-jni.c` is just a dummy file, where the `JNI` code would belong to, so that it becomes accessible.